# Blade bootstrap foreach get nice-looking grid-system

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, grid, laravel-blade

I'm having this piece of code in my Laravel's Blade view:

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  @if(isset($question->task))
   <a href="{{URL::action('showTask', $question->task_id)}}"><h4> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> {{$question->Task->name}}</h4></a>
  @endif

  
  <blockquote >
    <a class="nostyle" href="{{URL::action('showQuestion',$question->id)}}" ><p

        @if($question->status==1)
          class="text-success"
        @endif
      >{{$question->text}}</p></a>
  <footer>Gevraagd door <strong>{{$question->Author->getFullName('mij') }}</strong> op <strong>{{DateConverter::dateToString($question->created_at)}}</strong></footer>
  
  @if($question->status==1)
    <span class="label label-success">Beantwoord</span>
  @endif 
</blockquote>

</div>
  @endforeach
```

Showing all the questions. I want them to be displayed in **nice rows of 3**. However, some texts (*$question->text*) are longer than others, therefore they won't always perfectly start a new row, but append to the shortest previous grid, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

What I want would be more like a table, three columns, and then a new row on the same height with three new items.

So I'm looking for a way to

- either return all the columns the same height
- or automatically adding and closing a row div after each three columns.

  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
@foreach(array_chunk($questions->all(), 3) as $threeQuestions)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($threeQuestions as $question)
            // Do everything here
            @if(isset($question->task))
                <a href="{{URL::action('showTask', $question->task_id)}}"><h4> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> {{$question->Task->name}}</h4></a>
            @endif

            // ...

        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Here, `$threeQuestions` contains three items per iteration, so `.row` will keep each three items within a `div` like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    item-1
    item-2
    item-3
</div>
<div class='row'>
    item-4
    item-5
    item-6
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but array_chunck doesn't return anything unfortunately

Comment: I've figuredout why: the ->toarray() should be ->all()